# Creating an interface just to decouple from third party libraries

Tags: c#, design, design-patterns, .net, interfaces

I'm currently developing the Authorization module on a framework of mine.

I have the following class so far:

```
public interface IAuthorizationManager<C>
       where C : AuthorizationConfiguration
{
    void Configure(C configuration);
}
```

One of my implementations is going to be OAuth authentication.

For that I have created the following manager:

```
public class OAuthAuthorizationManager : IAuthorizationManager<OAuthConfiguration>
{
    private IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider _authorizationProvider;
    private IAuthenticationTokenProvider _refreshTokenProvider;

    public AuthorizationManager(IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider authorizationProvider,
                                IAuthenticationTokenProvider refreshTokenProvider)
    {
        this._authorizationProvider = authorizationProvider;
        this._refreshTokenProvider = refreshTokenProvider;
    }

    public void Configure(OAuthConfiguration configuration)
    {
       configuration.Application.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions() {
             AllowInsecureHttp = !configuration.IsSecure,
             TokenEndpointPath = new PathString(configuration.TokenEndpoint),
             AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = configuration.TokenExpiration,
             Provider = _authorizationProvider,
             RefreshTokenProvider = _refreshTokenProvider
       });
       configuration.Application.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
    }
}
```

Now, here's the thing, the implementations of `IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` and `IAuthenticationTokenProvider` are going to be injected through the constructor.

I am using Ninject for dependency injection.

In my application's startup project I have the following module:

```
public class AuthorizationModule : ApplicationModule
{
      public override void Load()
      {
          Kernel.Bind<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>().To<AuthorizationProvider<User, Client>>();
          Kernel.Bind<IAuthenticationTokenProvider>().To<RefreshTokenProvider<RefreshToken>();

          Kernel.Bind<IAuthorizationManager<OAuthConfiguration>>().To<OAuthAuthorizationManager>();
      }
}
```

The problem is that the interfaces `IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` and `IAuthenticationTokenProvider` are part of the `Owin.Security.OAuth` library, so when I am configuring the injection, my application's startup project needs to directly reference this library and its dependencies. This pollutes my `packages.config`. I don't like the idea to have the same library referenced twice in my solution, when only one project actually uses it.

`AuthorizationProvider<User, Client>` and `RefreshTokenProvider<RefreshToken>` are classes of mine, so there's no problem with those.

I was thinking of maybe creating an interface like this (of course i'd chose another name):

```
public class IMyOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider : IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider { }

public class IMyAuthenticationTokenProvider : IAuthenticationTokenProvider { }
```

Along with the associated changes:

```
public AuthorizationManager(IMyOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider authorizationProvider, IMyAuthenticationTokenProvider refreshTokenProvider)
{
    this._authorizationProvider = authorizationProvider;
    this._refreshTokenProvider = refreshTokenProvider;
}
```

And:

```
Kernel.Bind<IMyOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>().To<AuthorizationProvider<User, Client>>();
Kernel.Bind<IMyAuthenticationTokenProvider>().To<RefreshTokenProvider<RefreshToken>>();
```

Of course the `Owin.Security.OAuth` will keep being referenced, but this time indirectly, therefore I don't need to install them (via NuGet) on my main project.

I wanted to know if this is a common practice, what are the disadvantages of this approach, and any tips or alternative solution would be highly (and gladly) accepted.

Comment: Did you try that? You need to reference the assembly of the base-type to use a derived type.

Answer (score 3):

Does Ninject provide a configuration-file based approach (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092780/ninject-dependency-binding-from-xml))? I think if you did that the type would be dynamically loaded, and voila! - no dependency in your project.

The drawback is that now you have potential runtime failures rather than compile-time ones, but I think that's what you would rather have in your situation.

Comment: This is very interesting. I would prefer a compile time safe solution, but nevertheless this is pretty much feasible and solves my problem just as asked